# How to check whether two tuples in the list of lists are not same

Tags: python

```
lt1 = [(1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 5), (1, 4), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2)]
```

How can I report an error if (1,1) in the above list or some other tuple occurs more than once

Similarly for the list

```
lt22 = [['a', (1,1)], ['a', (1,2)], ['a', (1,2)], ['a', (1,3)], ['b', (2,1)], ['b', (2,2)], ['b', (2,2)]]
```

How to report an error if ['a', (1,2)] or any other element occurs more than once

Comment: For some reason I've now got the image of Bob from Sesame Street singing "One of these things is not like the others..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a set and a loop; the set will let you know if you've seen an element before:

```
seen = set()
for el in lt1:
    if el in seen:
        raise ValueError, 'More than one %r in your list' % (el,)
    seen.add(el)
```

Note that for mutable elements such as found in your second list, you want to convert these to non-mutable variants such as tuples first:

```
seen = set()
for el in lt22:
    el = tuple(el)
    if el in seen:
        raise ValueError, 'More than one %r in your list' % (el,)
    seen.add(el)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to detect it, not see exactly what element(s) occur more than once, you can just do:

```
if len(lt1) != len(set(lt1)):
    # Not all unique
```

In the second example you need to map the lists to tuples before converting to a set:

```
if len(lt22) != len(set(map(tuple, lt22))):
    # Not all unique
```

If you want to know how many times each item occurred, use `collections.Counter`, which was introduced in python 2.7:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> {k: d for k, d in Counter(lt1).items() if d > 1}
{(1, 1): 2}
```

Again, you must map `lt22` to `tuple` before using it to have it work.

If you just need a list of *which* items occur more than once, Martijns solution is probably the most efficient at that particular task.